# getview is not called in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with my custom adapter. the method getView() is not called. I searched on my friends "google" and "stackoverflow" but anything fix my problem.

```
public class custom_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<Activities> listData;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public custom_adapter(Context context,
            List<Activities> listActivity) {
        this.listData = listActivity;
        layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(context);
        Log.v("BaseAdapter", "custom_adapter");   
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         Log.v("BaseAdapter - getCount", String.valueOf(listData.size())); 
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("BaseAdapter", "getView");
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.averageRatingBarActivitySearch);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Activities newsItem = (Activities) listData.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(newsItem.getName());
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(newsItem.getAverageMark());

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getPictureActivityString());
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        RatingBar ratingBar;
        ImageView imageView;
    }


}
```

Furthermore, GetCount is not null !

I will be very glade if you can help me

Regards

K.L

Comment: Did you set your adapter to ListView?

Comment: either the answer is the above, or you  listData.size() returns 0

Comment: post your listview xml part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of handling List of some objects, extending generic `ArrayAdapter` may be better choice instead of just `BaseAdapter`. It will handle a lot of things for you. Your whole adapter class could look like.

```
public class ActivitiesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Activities>
{
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public ActivitiesAdapter(Context context, List<Activities> objects)
{
    super(context, 0, objects);

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.v("BaseAdapter", "getView");
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_adapter, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.averageRatingBarActivitySearch);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Activities newsItem = getItem(position);

    holder.name.setText(newsItem.getName());
    holder.ratingBar.setRating(newsItem.getAverageMark());

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getPictureActivityString());
    }

    return convertView;
}


public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

and of course you have to set this adapter to your `ListView` instance. Like

```
ActivitiesAdapter adapter = new ActivitiesAdapter(this, yourActivitiesList);
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list_id);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or simply `setListAdapter(adapter);` if you are using `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`;

Comment: Thanks a lot, The problem isn't in my custom_adapter class but in my listView.I use listView.setAdapter(adapter) instead of setListAdapter(adapter);

Comment: You have to call "super();"  method in your array adapter's constructor. You did not call it that's why getView() method didn't call.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Maybe, the problem is that you don't notify your adapter that you've changed data in the adapter. Try this code in your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

And call `notifyDataSetChanged();` when you change the data in Adapter.